# Tooltip with the question's tags in the hot questions column

Tags: feature-request, tags, user-interface, hot-questions, tooltips

When browsing Stack Exchange sites, I often notice questions that may interest me in the Hot Questions column, however they sometimes have titles that don't exactly tell what product/game/software/technology they are about (very frequent for Arqade's questions) and the only way to know that is to open the question - not very efficient in my opinion.

This is my feature request - display all the question's tags in a tooltip for a quick look without needing to open the question :

[image: Feature's screenshot]

Comment: Alternatively, you could display only the first, main tag (that will still tell you what game on Arqade or book on scifi.se the question is about), but make it visible without mousing over, perhaps between the site logo and question title

Comment: Didn't realize I was making an exact duplicate of this feature request.

Comment: I was also writing an exact dupe of this question just because of hot Arqade questions. This should definitely happen.